# Angular js when i use http.get in a controller function then it is not rendering response data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I want to render the response of the `http.get()` function of angularJS, actually the problem is that when i use `http.get` in a controller function then it is not rendering response data.

View:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="dtlCtrl"  >
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table  class="table  table-striped">
            <thead>
                <th> Name</th>
                <th >Storage</th>
                <th >Credits</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="a in credits" >
                    <td><a  href="#">{{ a.username }}</a></td>
                    <td>{{ a.storage }}</td>
                    <td>{{ a.credits }}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>    
        </table>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
    <div class="modal-footer ">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg" style="width: 100%;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign"></span> Update</button>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- /.modal-content --> 
</div>
<!-- /.modal-dialog --> 
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
app.controller('dtlCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    //var count;
    //window.names=" ";   
    //count=0;
    $scope.crd=function(name) {  
        // alert("http://localhost:8080/ZenCameraAdmin/admin/getusercredits?username="+name);
        // count=1;
        $scope.credits;
        window.names=name;
        //alert(window.names);
        $http.get("http://192.168.0.87:8080/ZenCameraAdminServices/admin/getusercredits?username="+window.names)
        .success(function (response) {$scope.credits = response.credits;
            //console.log(response.plans);
        });
        //alert(window.names);
        console.log($scope.credits);
        return $scope.credits;
    };
});
```

Comment: Are you getting a response at all? Does `192.168.0.87:8080` have CORS configured?

Comment: please check and see if the rest call is successful, you dont catch the errors.

Comment: remember you use promise trying to do console.log($scope.credits); outside the controller might not be filled because the result has not been received.

Comment: You are over-writing the reference to `$scope.credits`.  Try to `push` the results into the existing array.

Comment: Why are you wrapping everything in the `$scope.crd` function?  Where is that bound to the template?

Comment: Andy Gaskell ,i dont have an issue with CORS ,only the issue is that i am getting the response but it is not render .. ,i thought it is due to function that i used crd ,please give any suggestion so i can resolve it,,

Comment: i used $scope.crd for getting specific user ,please tell some alternative @Davin Tryon

Comment: The fact that the code is *returning* `$scope.credits` is a bit strange.  The binding should happen only in the success callback.

Comment: when i used http.get() without any function it renders response but when i used function it is not render @DavinTryon